# How to fetch Instagram profile picture with php?

Tags: php, api, instagram

I've been trying for a few days to fetch Instagram Profile Picture through the API, using the official website : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started.

I changed a few things and I'm able to fetch the code and token, but after that I'm stuck. It seems like it's deprecated.

I would lile to do something like this :
https://downloadgram.org/profile-picture-downloader.php

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need to give us a proper problem description, not "I'm stuck." What seems like it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to get the profile picture through a standard api call anymore. However, workarounds have been developed.

See [instagram-private-api](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) which is implemented [here](https://github.com/yasinatesim/instagram-fullsize-picture) and you can test [here](https://instagram-fullsize-picture.yasinatesim.vercel.app/). Note that this is in Node and not php though.